# In Azure Functions, where do we put settings we want to put on Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

So just started playing with Azure Functions, I have a new project with some appsettings in the local.settings.json file.

So this works on my local, but obviously when I deploy to Azure Functions, local.settings.json file isn't used.

Where are we supposed to specify our settings for an Azure Function?

Is there a azure.settings.json file? Or some sort of way to deploy an settings file during the deployment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to add settings, you could use the way provided by Matt, and if you want to deploy the Function to Azure with the settings in the `local.settings.json`, there is another way to implement it.

Install the [Azure Functions Core Tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local) on the local, publish the Function with `-publish-local-settings -i` and if you are using the version 2 `the --publish-settings-only -o` could only publish settings and skip the content.

The below pic is a sample, you could find it will prompt to overwrite value in azure if setting is different between azure and `local.settings.json`.

[image]

Further more information, you could refer to this tutorial: [Publish to Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local#publish).

Answer (score 2):

Just like an Azure App Service, and Azure Function has an [Application Settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-how-to-use-azure-function-app-settings#settings) tab where you can configure these through the Azure Portal. To access these you go to: `Your function app > Overview > Configured Features> Configuration`, you can then add the settings that you need under the `Application Settings` tab.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ppv9U.png]

Alternatively, if you would prefer configuring these through a CLI then that option is [also available](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/cli/azure/functionapp/config/appsettings?view=azure-cli-latest#az-functionapp-config-appsettings-set). The main documentation is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-app-settings).

---

**Edit**

For a solution as part of your CI/CD you have two options (examples will use Azure DevOps and perform the action in the CD step):

- [PowerShell Task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-powershell?view=azure-devops). You could add a Powershell (or any type of script that will talk to the Azure CLI for functions) script as part of your CD step. [This post](https://www.bilot.fi/automating-azure-functions-deployment-with-azure-devops/) goes through the process step by step, the bit you are probably interested in is under "Deploying with Azure DevOps Release Pipeline". Essentially it is building up a collection of your appsetting keys and their values, then a call to `Set-AzureRmWebApp` the and pass in the collection to the `-AppSettings` flag as per [these docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.websites/set-azurermwebapp?view=azurermps-6.13.0)
- [Azure CLI task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-cli?view=azure-devops). Same as above but you could use the Azure CLI task along with the Inline script option to call the `az functionapp config appsettings set` command [docs here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/cli/azure/functionapp/config/appsettings?view=azure-cli-latest#az-functionapp-config-appsettings-set). The `--settings` flag takes:

> Space-separated app settings in a format of =.

So

```
az functionapp config appsettings set --name MyFunctionApp --resource-group MyResourceGroup --settings "settings1Key=settings1Value settings2Key=settings2value"
```

The `Azure Functions for .NET` template for CI (Build) and `Deploy a function app to Azure Functions` template for CD (Release) inside Azure DevOps will come in handy.

Comment: Sure you can set it manually. But I wanted a solution that set as part of your deployment and included in source code. The azure cli set function only does one variable at a time and doesn't allow you to set for a whole time

Comment: How did you go @Diskdrive?